# Wilcoxon Z score is negative when it should be positive and vice versa

Tags: sas

SAS Coding: - I perform a ttest on the differences in two groups (independent but from same population). The signs of the 'difference' amount and the t-stat match (i.e. mathematical difference between the two groups is negative and tstat is negative. Or if mathematical difference between the two groups is positive the tstat is positive).

However, when I run a wilcoxon rank sum test, the signs of my z-scores don't match the sign (-/+) of the group difference. (i.e. mathematical difference between the two groups is negative but z-score is positive. If mathematical difference between the two groups is positive the z-score is negative).

I have tried sorting the dataset regular and descending.

Here's my code:

```
*proc sort data = fundawin3t;
    by vb_nvb_TTest;
run;

**Wilcoxon rank sums for vb vs nvb firms.;
proc npar1way data = fundawin3t wilcoxon;
    title "NVB vs VB univariate tests and Wilcoxon-Table 4";
    var  ma_score_2015 age mve roa BM BHAR prcc_f  CFI CFF momen6 vb_nvb SERIAL recyc_v;
    class vb_nvb_TTest;
run;
```

Here is my log:

```
3208
3209  proc sort data = fundawin3t;
3210      by vb_nvb_TTest;
3211  run;

NOTE: Input data set is already sorted, no sorting done.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SORT used (Total process time):
  real time           0.00 seconds
  cpu time            0.01 seconds


3212
3213  **Wilcoxon rank sums for vb vs nvb firms.;
3214  proc npar1way data = fundawin3t wilcoxon;
3215      title "NVB vs VB univariate tests and Wilcoxon-Table 4";
3216      var  ma_score_2015 age mve roa BM BHAR prcc_f  CFI CFF momen6 
tenure vb_nvb SERIAL
3216! recyc_v;
3217      class vb_nvb_TTest;
3218  run;

NOTE: PROCEDURE NPAR1WAY used (Total process time):
      real time           6.59 seconds
      cpu time            5.25 seconds
```

Comment: Is your proc SORT commented out as in the code you posted? Post your log please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTM

To compute the linear rank statistic S, PROC NPAR1WAY sums the scores of the observations in the smaller of the two samples. If both samples have the same number of observations, PROC NPAR1WAY sums those scores for the sample that appears first in the input data set.

PROC NPAR1WAY computes one-sided and two-sided asymptotic p-values for each two-sample linear rank test. When the test statistic z is greater than its null hypothesis expected value of 0, PROC NPAR1WAY computes the right-sided p-value, which is the probability of a larger value of the statistic occurring under the null hypothesis. When the test statistic is less than or equal to 0, PROC NPAR1WAY computes the left-sided p-value, which is the probability of a smaller value of the statistic occurring under the null hypothesis. The one-sided p-value $P_1(z)$ can be expressed as

Comment: Thank you RTM. I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong from your comments.